# AngularJS wait to compile/link/repeat until user clicks

Tags: performance, angularjs

I'm experiencing some performance issues on a medium-sized result set. The result set is a list of documents, each with a small array of properties (metadata like created, modified, tags, owner_name, etc.) that is hidden until the user clicks a show/hide button.

In the template, I'm using a lot of `ng-show`s, and when I comment all of these out, the performance improves dramatically, so I was wondering if there is a way to ask Angular not to compile any of this, not to render any of the ng-repeats until the user clicks the properties show/hide button. Or is there a more idiomatic way of going about this?

**Update:** actually, it isn't when I comment out the `ng-show`s, it seems to be when I comment out the entire block of html, making it seem like accessing properties of an object is the cause of the performance hit. Why?

Template:

```
 <div class="property" ng-show="property.display && property.value && property.viewable" ng-repeat="property in item.properties()">

     <span class="property-name">{{property.external}}:</span>
     <span class="property-value" ng-show="property.type == 'string' || property.type == 'integer' || property.type == 'float'">
         <span ng-hide="property.edit">{{property.value}}</span>
         <span ng-show="property.edit">
             <input name="{{property.internal}}" id="{{property.internal}}{{item.id()}}" />
             <span class="edit-button"><a ng-click="simpleUpdate(item, property)">save</a></span>
             <span class="edit-button"><a ng-click="editProperty(item, property)">cancel</a></span>
         </span>
            <span class="edit-button" ng-show="property.editable && !property.edit"><a ng-click="editProperty(item, property)">edit</a></span>
     </span>                

     <span class="property-value" ng-show="property.type == 'stringArray'">
         <span ng-hide="property.edit">{{property.value | join:', '}}</span>
         <span ng-show="property.edit">
             <textarea name="{{property.internal}}" id="{{property.internal}}{{item.id()}}" class="keywords" rows="1" cols="80"></textarea>
             <span class="edit-button"><a ng-click="simpleUpdate(item, property)">save</a></span>
             <span class="edit-button"><a ng-click="editProperty(item, property)">cancel</a></span>
         </span>
         <span class="edit-button" ng-show="property.editable && !property.edit"><a ng-click="editProperty(item, property)">edit</a></span>
     </span>

     <div class="clearboth">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you put your code to plunker with generation of lot of fake documents and properties in them? Then we can profile (Chrome DevTools and AngularJS Batarang extension have some profiling tools).